# How to make Unity UI object draggable when the objects are instantiating at runtime?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools, unity-ui

I am working on a management game where every user has some specific characters in save files. I am instantiating these characters inside a panel, I want the user to choose one of the cards and drag it to some specific point. I am able to make a drag script for the object that is already in a scene. But how to achieve the same thing if objects are generating at runtime?
I just need some idea how to do it.
here's my current code to drag UI object.

```
    public void OnDrag(){
    btn.transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
}
public void EndDrag(){
    if (btn.transform.position.x -500 <50 || btn.transform.position.x -500 > -50) {
        //btn.transform.position = new Vector3 (-10, 10);
        rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (500, 100, 0);
    }
    else{
        rt.anchoredPosition = new Vector3 (-10, -10, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, what classes or objects have you written in your project? Character ? CharacterCard ? Can one character have more than one Character Card or is it 1:1 ? Are the cards contained where?

Comment: Cards are instantiating as images. I can already Instantiate cards and put them in a panel. Everything is working fine, Only thing i need to know is that how can i write a draggable script for an object that instantiate at runtime.

Comment: @ghayoor you can create a prefab of your object and attach dragging-script to this prefab. And when you'll instantiate your object, it will already has your script

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the time you Instantiate your GameObject obj, do:

```
obj.addComponent("YourScript");
```

where YourScript is your script, which you have written, that attached to a GameObjects makes it draggable..

Alternatively, you instantiate a prefab, attach the script to the prefab through the editor.

This is preferrable because [addComponent()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html) will get deprecated in the next versions.

I also recommend to keep a `List<YourInstantiatedObjectType>` in the parent.

Comment: I am using (OnDrag and EndDrag events) from eventTrigger and then using those two functions(OnDrag and endDrag) in these events. 
If there is any better way of doing this, Please let me know.

Comment: Where is the script that uses OnDrag attached? To what GameObject?

Comment: What if I use MouseDrag event? Will it be fit for my current scenario?

Comment: you should handle different drag events per different objects being dragged. therefore one script per object...

Comment: It is attached to an Empty gameObject.

Comment: Eh not good. You basically detect an overall click and drag one statically known object. You should have your script work only for THAT object when you click it and update its transform.

Comment: Okay, what if I do this.
Add the script to prefab and simply use OnMouseDrag to drag object? is it okay?

Comment: Yeah. Make it update the transform of that specific object.

Comment: I got it Thank you very much.